# Content-Security-Policy help needed

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-security-policy

Hey guys I got a problem with applying Content-Security-Policy to website.

well its works fine for me on main website:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.example.pl *.youtube.com *.google.com *.linkedin.com *.fontawesome.com *.jsdelivr.net *.smartsuppcdn.com *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com *.example.com.pl; *.example.pl/blog/wp-content"
</IfModule>
```

But there is problem with wordpress blog, when i visit example.pl/blog there is no images on website.

I dont know if I should look for some file in wordpress to apply this stuff there? or should I look for some other solution?
Anyway I'm looking for your advices :)

@EDIT 1

I found out that If I add this policy all of my plugins on WP don't work, same goes for main website, I have Smartsupp app for chating with clients and its turn offline when I add this Policy to .htaccess.

Could some1 send me article or something how can I turn on this policy well?

Comment: If something is blocked by CSP, it should show up in the developer console with more details usually

Comment: @ChrisHaas I find out that CSP is bloking my wordpress plugins, so when i turn off some of plugins in this blog, website its work it display images etc, but the point is that i dont want to disable all plugins, any idea how to add plugins from Wordpress to this .htaccess file in my main website? :^)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your developer console should list the things that are being blocked, and you can then add those as additional exceptions. Also, you are using `unsafe-inline`, which [people](https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-inline/) strongly [recommend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_inline_script) against using, and the places you whitelist also [allow bypass](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/). As for WordPress, just put an .htaccess file in that folder that unset this policy.

Comment: okey i did like u said but... there is to much of scripts loading on website, and i cant put everything in one line. I think that i have to put everything in one line in .htaccess to make it work well isnt it? or mb u know how can I do line brake in htaccess to make it work?

Comment: To break the line in `.htaccess` file or Apache config you can use a [backslash](http://csplite.com/csp31/#htaccess) `\\` at the end of line. A next line should start immediately without leading spaces.